# Java Canvas Drawing

Tags: java, canvas, paint

Edit 4: A new formatting for the question

BACKGROUND: I have a class, Window, that extends JFrame, In the JFrame I have a canvas.
To the canvas I add custom objects. The only purpose of this object(for argumenst sake) is to print a circle with text to the canvas. You can add multiple of these custom components to the canvas. When you add a new custom component it is placed 20 pixels(for now) away from the previous component added to the canvas.

PROBLEM: The canvas places the second circle at a position lets call it A,  A is approximately in the centre of the form, The third circle added is placed at a position B, B is all the way to the right of the canvas, when more circles are added both positions A and B shift left.  Irrespective of what I specify as the x and y coordinates of the drawOval function in the paint method this happens.

QUESTION: Is there a setting/function/option related to objects that you draw to eg Canvas and JFrame that will put the objects drawn to it at preset positions instead of where it is specified to draw

#

Everything posted before edit4:

Does a canvas in java have some sort of setting that I can disable which makes it place items where it wants.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
  System.out.println("paint   X: "+x+"  Y: "+y);
  g.drawOval(x, y, RAD , RAD);
  System.out.println("paint 2nd   X: "+x+"  Y: "+y);
```

}

The following code does not place two circles at the same position when x and y are hard coded the .out's prove that x,y do not change so I am at a loss.( when two different objects call their draw function every one after the first one is placed at predefined positions but not where I specify it)

Edit:  I have made a jar file that you can check to see what I mean, if you add a new node it should only be 60pixels away from the previous, and at a constant position. It can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11041476/Projek.jar)

Edit2: I don't really know what code you could need, I do have a lot of code. Like explained before I have a JFrame, On the Jframe there is a canvas, to clarify more, I have objects which extend component each of which use the above code snippet as paint(which to my understanding gets called when repaint is called on the canvas) if you look at the example you can click the add node button, the first object (node) gets put at 0,0 which is correct, the second node you add should be placed 60 pixels to the right of the previous node added, but the second one you add always gets placed at around the centre of the canvas, no matter what the coordinates of that second item even if I hard code them. If you right click you can also add a new node and that node should be placed where you right clicked but also gets added to a random position on the canvas I have checked and double check the coordinates the function recieve so nothing at all is wrong with my coordinates, thats why the starting line of my question asks how to get the Items to be plaed where I am drawing them and not where the canvas wanst to place them.

Edit3:  Aperantly my question is still unclear If you can look a the jar, and you have java installed you can run the jar with the folowing command assuming the jar is in your current directory in command prompt C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_04\bin\java.exe -jar Projek.jar,  and for linux just java -jar Projek.jar  . Ok for more code snippets.

In the Window class

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements   ActionListener{
...
Canvas panel;
...
private int globalX;
private int globalY;
...
public Window(){
...
graph=new Graph();

    panel = new Canvas();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
...
container.add(panel);
    container.add(btn_newNode,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
      });

    setSize(1024,758);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
//Add Node gets called when you click on the button
public void addNode(String name){

    int ix;
    int iy;
    String itext=name;

    if(name.compareTo(".print") != 0){
    if(graph.VertexCount() > 0){
    Vertex temp=graph.getVertex(graph.VertexCount());

    if((temp.x + 20) < panel.getWidth() ){
        ix=temp.x + 20;
        iy=temp.y;
    }
    else{
        ix=temp.x;
        iy=temp.y + 20;
    }
    } else {
        ix=0;
        iy=0;
    }
        Vertex a=new Vertex(itext,ix,iy);
        graph.addVertex(a);
        panel.add(a);
        panel.revalidate();
      } else System.out.println(graph.toString());
    }


  public class Vertex<T> extends Component {
  private T data;
  public int x;
  public int y;
public final int RAD=50;
public Vertex( T data,int _x,int _y) {
incomingEdges = new ArrayList<Edge<T>>();
outgoingEdges = new ArrayList<Edge<T>>();
visited = false;
this.data = data;
x=_x;
y=_y;
System.out.println("X: "+x+"  Y: "+y);

}
public void paint(Graphics g){
  System.out.println("paint   X: "+x+"  Y: "+y);
  g.drawString(data.toString(), x+4, y+27);
  g.drawOval(x, y, RAD , RAD);

  //g.drawOval(20, 0, RAD , RAD);
  System.out.println("paint 2nd   X: "+x+"  Y: "+y);
}
```

That is everything that I can think is relavant, But I have been wrong before ^

Comment: There is only one `drawOvel()` method.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I should have mentioned multiple objects call that function each with their own x,y coordinates

Comment: @Chaosekie: "I don't really know what code you could need,.."  We don't need any, given it is not our responsibility to solve the bug.  But for the sake of *you* getting answers, I recommend you post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: BTW - why code using AWT in this millennium?

Comment: @Chaosekie: "On the Jframe there is a canvas,.."  Don't mix Swing with AWT, no matter what millennium you are coding in.

Comment: Use a `JFrame` with a `JComponent` for the custom painting.  When doing custom painting in Swing components (other than top level containers) override `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

Comment: I did try a Jframe, but it did excatly the same as canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Vertex components are being added to a container (the Canvas) with a GridLayout. GridLayout is trying to position/bound the Vertex components. The coordinate system in the paint method of the Vertex is relative to the position/bounds of the component. You're mixing two coordinate systems and object hierarchies. Unless you *REALLY need the Vertex to be a component*, I could reorganize your object structure. If you DO need Vertex to be a component then you'll want to use NO layout manger (or a custom manager) and use the Component coordinates for the Vertex objects for rendering. The solution is very different depending on your requirements.

Comment: HAHA your obsolutely right!!!! See my problem was this and netbeans, see since I was working on the project the whole day netbeans was open the whole day, It had somehow loaded a class from a previous project I had worked on which had a class named Canvas in it but which was actually a modified JForm,  so yes the canvas was actually a Form which loaded everything according to the grid.The way I figured this out was with looking at the documentation and I found it funny that i was able to set a Layout to the canvas which ddoesnt allow for setting of a layout.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled netbeans and everythiing is working as expected. +1 (*infinity)

Answer (score 4):

The method signature for [drawOval](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) is:

```
public abstract void drawOval(int x,
                              int y,
                              int width,
                              int height)
```

The result is a circle or ellipse that fits within the rectangle specified by the x, y, width, and height arguments.

The x and y position are relative to the canvas, and are **not** the center of the oval.  They represent a position to the upper left of the oval.

The width and height, when they are the same, are the diameter of the circle, not the radius.

Edited to respond to changes in the question.

Some of us cannot access web file storage.  We are at work, and our firewalls do not allow us access.  Even if we could access it, it's a lot of trouble to download a jar, unpack the jar, and open up an IDE to see what you're doing.  If you want our help, you need to put some effort in asking the question.

Calling the `drawOval` method draws an oval based on the parameters passed.  If the oval is not in the correct place on the canvas, then the parameters are wrong.

Finally, for the benefit of others coming across this answer in the future.  If you want to draw a circle, and you have a center point x, y, and a radius RAD, then the following method call will draw the circle you're expecting.

```
g.drawOval(x - RAD, y - RAD, RAD + RAD, RAD + RAD);
```

Comment: Yes dit you even look at the example, i don't mean to be a jack ass but I know how to use the java documentation, just look at the example.

Comment: Your "example" lacks any useful context. He was going on as much as you gave him...

Comment: @Chaosekie: I did look at the example.  Your example has fields x, y, and RAD.  Nowhere do you tell us what x, y, and RAD are.  Also, I find RAD to be a funny abbreviation for diameter.

Comment: I am sorry for sounding so crude I have spent the better part of today figuring this out, I have no spend 8 hours straight on this without sucess,  RAD is a constant for Radius which I agree is a misnomer, it shoudl be diameter. x,y are the coordinates where the Item shoudl be placed they are members of the class in which this paint function resides, they get set when the class is constructed. The context is unimportant, but the example is a gui for a graph data structure which will be used to module classes by doing topological sortin gon the graph

Comment: the circles represent the verteces or nodes, I cannot add the edges(lines that connect each ) without the nodes being at the correct position on the canvas

Comment: by example I mean the jar I added, if you feel it might be some kind of virus I am trying to feed you I will also post the entire source code

Comment: @Chaosekie:  Java Swing requires methods to be called in a certain order to display properly.  I can't help you unless you put more effort into asking questions.  We don't want the entire source code.  We want you to isolate the problem so you can ask a question that can be answered.

Comment: @Chaosekie: "I have edited the question pleaase take a look"  I have posted a link to the SSCCE, *please* take a look.  That 78 lines of (poorly formatted) code snippets does not compile, and is not likely to get much attention or help.