# Java Applet program: "Bold Circle" issue

Tags: java, applet, awt, java-2d

I would like to make an applet which displays a "Bold circle", like a series of concentric circles which give as a result a more "thick" circumference.

I have tried this two ways but they don't really work:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class BoldCircle extends JApplet
{
   public void paint(Graphics canvas)
   {
      int i;

      for(i=150; i < 160; i++)
         canvas.drawOval(200, 200, i, i);  


      for(i=500; i < 510; i++)
         canvas.drawOval(  i,   i, 150, 150);
   }

}
```

[Program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyf8m.png)

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6110920/2055998

Comment: The basic answer to the question is *"Use a **`Graphics2D`** instance and set a thick `Stroke` for drawing"*. On other matters: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. Note that Swing offers a ..

Comment: **`Graphics2D`** object for custom painting (which is done in the `paintComponent(..)` method rather than the `paint(..)` method like AWT).